# Angular service coming back as Object

Tags: angularjs

I have a service in my Angular app called refstorage :

```
.service('RefStorage',function($window){
     var refnum = {}
 function set(data) {
   refnum = data;
 }
 function get() {
  return refnum;
 }

 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }
})
```

When i call this from my controller like this :

```
var refNum = RefStorage.get();
```

Its returning as `[object Object]`, i was expecting a string. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: You set `refnum` to an object at the beginning of your service - `var refnum = {};`. Unless you've run `set` first to replace it with a string, it makes sense that an object is what it would return.

Answer (score 2):

Because you initialize `refnum` as an object:

```
var refnum = {};
```

So obviously, if you don't call `set()` first, `get()` will return an object.

Comment: That's fine, everyone is allowed to have a PEBCAK from time to time, glad to be your rubber duck ;-)